# Most listened song on each day

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have the following data

```
date            user    song
..........      .....   .....
2017-07-12      u1      song1
2017-07-12      u2      song1
2017-07-12      u1      song1
2017-07-12      u2      song2
2017-07-12      u1      song3
2017-07-12      u2      song1
2017-07-12      u1      song2
2017-07-12      u2      song1
2017-07-13      u1      song2      
2017-07-13      u2      song2
2017-07-13      u1      song2
2017-07-13      u2      song1
2017-07-13      u1      song1
```

i want the following output

```
date                       song
..........                 .....
2017-07-12                 song1
2017-07-13                 song2
```

I was able to get the count and song name but unable to pick top one on each day.I have used the following query

```
SELECT 
dt,song_name,count(song_name) as c
FROM es_session GROUP BY 
dt,song_name order by c,dt DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called the "mode" in statistics.  You can calculate it using window functions:

```
SELECT ds.*
FROM (SELECT dt, song_name, count(song_name) as c,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dt ORDER BY COUNT(song_name) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM es_session
      GROUP BY dt, song_name
     ) ds
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY c, dt DESC ;
```

If there are duplicates, this will choose an arbitrary value.  If you want all of them, use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: one user has heard a song many number of times.The user must be taken as a distinct field